# Some of my ASP files on windows 7 aren't loaded even though I installed IIS

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, iis

I don't know how to get my asp code to work on windows 7. I ran my project, it works correctly.

But for some pages I'm getting an `HTTP 401.5` error. Can someone help me?

Comment: check the permissions on the files that are returning that error

Comment: If some pages have the errors and other do not then its probably a file permission error. Copy the permissions from asp files that work on to those that do not work. Or *inherit* the permissions from parent folder.

Answer (score 1):

enable the fail request tracing.
http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/266/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis-7/